# EXIF tag and hex code for 'Tags' and 'Authors' for jpg image

Tags: c#, exif

I am unable to co-relate the actual EXIF tag for 'Tags' and 'Authors' which you can see in Image properties. Can someone help me see which one of it corresponds to it?

ps. I am referring to the list of EXIF tags [here on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.imaging.propertyitem.id.aspx) -

[image: Image properties]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's my guess at the properties:

Authors =  [PropertyTagArtist](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms534416.aspx#_gdiplus_constant_propertytagartist) (`0x013B`)

> (Null-terminated character string that specifies the name of the
>   person who created the image.)

Tags = [PropertyTagExifUserComment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms534416%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#_gdiplus_constant_propertytagexifusercomment) (`0x9286`)

> Comment tag. A tag used by EXIF users to write keywords or comments about the image
>   besides those in PropertyTagImageDescription and without the character-code limitations 
>   of the PropertyTagImageDescription tag.

I edited a jpeg in windows explorer per the OP example screenshot and ran it thru [ExifTool](http://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/).
Output contained the value I added for `Author` as `Artist`, `XP Author`, and `Creator`. It listed the value I added for `Tags` as `XP Keywords`, `Subject`, and `Last Keyword XMP`.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It's 0x9c9e, which isn't listed on the page you cited.  You can find this by adding a tag to an image, then running exif to see the name of the field ("XP Keywords"), and then running exif -l on the file to list all the fields, and grepping for the field name.